# How to find the missing memory: disparity between `ps` and `free -m`

Tags: linux, memory, centos7, ps

I am running centos7 that is installed in a virtual machine.

First, I ran this command:

```
free -m
total: 7720, used:6793, free:367, available:500, buffers:41, cached:517, slab:397.
```

But  when I run `ps`, it reports that rss total memory is 2791.6M.

```
ps -eo 'pid,rss' --sort=-rss |awk '{sum += $2} END {print sum/1024}'
```

so 3046.4M (= 6793 - 41 - 517 - 397 - 2791.6) is missing.

To eliminate the impact on the physical machines memory, i restarted the process, and the memory went down to a normal level.

questions: how to find the missing memory?

Comment: You might have better luck with this question on the superuser Stack Exchange site: https://superuser.com/

Comment: I find the problem by kill progress one by one. Thanks.